# How to recognize file pattern in azure blob input dataset

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This is my file pattern: adm_domain_20180401, adm_domain_20180402, these are from one particular source. same folder also contains adm_agent_20180401, adm_agent_20180402. I want to only copy files from blob to ADL with prefix adm_domain, is there any way to define the file pattern in input data set?

DATASET:

{
    "name": "CgAdmDomain",
    "properties": {
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": "flk_blob_dev_ls",
        "typeProperties": {
            "folderPath": "incoming/{Date}/",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat"
            },
            "partitionedBy": [
                {
                    "name": "Date",
                    "value": {
                        "type": "DateTime",
                        "date": "SliceStart",
                        "format": "yyyyMMdd"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        },
        "external": true,
        "policy": {}
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ADF V1 or V2?  We are working on adding filename wildcard support in ADF V2.

Comment: We are using ADF V1, how to define file patterns in ADF V1?

Answer (score 0):

The `fileFilter` is not available for `Azure Blob Storage`. If you are looking files at on-premise then you will be able to achieve this by specifying a filter to be used to select a subset of files in the `folderPath` rather than all files - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-onprem-file-system-connector)

To solely achieve this for `Azure Blob Storage` use `Azure Data Factory` Custom activities. Implement the logic through custom code (.NET) and have it as an activity in the pipeline. More info about how to use custom activites - [further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities).